# How to adequately combine a database and an LDAP directory?

Tags: database, architecture, ldap

I intend to build a system that stores information in a relational database (PostgreSQL) and in a directory (OpenLDAP).

- the directory is for the system's users (workers, customers, brokers), each of them has a UUID that uniquely identifies them;
- the database is for things that change often (e.g. order details, transactions currently in progress, etc);
- some tables in the database will have a UUID attribute, pointing to entities in OpenLDAP.

A directory is chosen because I want to leverage the ability to build entities that have variable sets of attributes, or entities that inherit or combine attributes from other classes of entities. Such flexibility is needed to support a wider range of business cases.

In other words, the directory provides some "object-orientedness", which would have to be reinvented from scratch, had I chosen to use an RDBMS exclusively.

There's a catch that I am not sure how to deal with yet: *if a table refers to a UUID that was removed from the directory - the database will effectively point to nothing*. Thus the data will become incomplete or inconsistent.

My solution is to *never remove entities from OpenLDAP, instead just mark them as "inactive"*.

My questions:

- is it common practice to utilize a directory and a relational database in such a way?
- are there other approaches that can solve the same problem using a single component?

Comment: Where do you plan to store application roles?  Will you map the unique ids to roles?  What is your problem of having a link to an id of a deleted user?  You cannot query the name and other information from directory to display in some interface?

Comment: Have you ever had a look at so called "NoSQL" Databases? Seems to me that that might solve your problem.

Comment: Have you considered the functional scenario's where an entry in your OpenLDAP directory might no longer exist?

Comment: Timothy, roles are stored in LDAP as attributes of an entity. The problem with having to link to deleted users is related to the distant future - someone might inherit the system then ignore the documentation and use those identifiers for some purpose, giving them more meaning than they have.

Comment: Jonathan, what do you mean by "functional scenario"?

Andreas, NoSQL is a very broad term that can mean a lot of different things. Do you have a specific instrument in mind?